# Display and Search the specific record in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am new to `ASP.NET` `MVC`. And I just wanted to ask about how to create search functionality that only search the specific records of the `logged` in current users and not all records from the database.

I tried this code in my index and I'm getting an error.

```
IEnumerable<Book> myBooks = db.Books.Where(x => 
x.BookTitle.Contains(searching) ||
searching == null).Where(x => x.User == currentUser).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are looking for records for a specific user

you need to use

```
IEnumerable<Book> myBooks = db.Books.Where(x => 
x.BookTitle.Contains(searching) ||
searching == null).Where(x => x.User.UserId == currentUser.UserId).ToList();
```

A word of note in C#, value types(int, long, etc) when used with the == operator are compared by value, references are compared by reference location, that means that the user you are referring to needs to be the same reference as the current user.

When using the object.Equals methods, it tries to compare the contents of the class type(in your case, the User object), e.g

> User.Id == o.UserId && UserId.Name == UserId.Name, etc

So use a valuetype like your int, etc that are unique to filter that out instead

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
List<Book> myBooks = db.Books.Where(x => 
    (x.BookTitle.Contains(searching) || x.BookTitle == null) && x.User == currentUser).ToList();
```

Comment: An explanation, what the posted code does and how this addresses the problem in the question, rarely fails to improve an answer.

Comment: @blue-phoenox the code is clear enough and I think no explanation is needed